# TypeScript array with minimum length

Tags: typescript

How can you create a type in TypeScript that only accepts arrays with two or more elements?

```
needsTwoOrMore(["onlyOne"]) // should have error
needsTwoOrMore(["one", "two"]) // should be allowed
needsTwoOrMore(["one", "two", "three"]) // should also be allowed
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Update 2021**: ***shorter notation:***

```
type arrMin1Str = [string, ...string[]]; // The minimum is 1 string.
```

OR

```
type arrMin2Strs = [string, string, ...string[]]; // The minimum is 2 strings.
```

OR

```
type arrMin3Strs = [string, string, string, ...string[]]; // The minimum is 3 strings.
```

OR *…so on*

This is just an addition to @KPD and @Steve Adams answers, since all specified types are the same.
This should be a valid syntax since TypeScript 3.0+ (2018).

Comment: Not the prettiest, but works like a charm!

Comment: causes TS2556 if a function is called like `foo(...myArray)`

Comment: Seems to have some other limitations too. For instance `[string, ...string[]]` is not regarded as equivalent to `[...string[], string]`.  If you have `x: string[]`, then `[...x, 'a']` will not match `arrMin1Str`.

Answer (score 67):

This can be accomplished with a type like:

```
type ArrayTwoOrMore<T> = {
    0: T
    1: T
} & Array<T>

declare function needsTwoOrMore(arg: ArrayTwoOrMore<string>): void

needsTwoOrMore(["onlyOne"]) // has error
needsTwoOrMore(["one", "two"]) // allowed
needsTwoOrMore(["one", "two", "three"]) // also allowed
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ArrayTwoOrMore%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%200%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%201%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%20%26%20Array%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20needsTwoOrMore(arg%3A%20ArrayTwoOrMore%3Cstring%3E)%3A%20void%0D%0A%0D%0AneedsTwoOrMore(%5B%22onlyOne%22%5D)%20%2F%2F%20has%20error%0D%0AneedsTwoOrMore(%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%5D)%20%2F%2F%20allowed%0D%0AneedsTwoOrMore(%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D)%20%2F%2F%20also%20allowed)

Comment: How do you do this with interface?
say `items: Item[] = [];`, I need to require atleast 1 `Item`

Comment: @ColdCerberus There is no difference. The `Item[]` syntax is just sugar for `Array<Item>`. So just like the example in the answer had `ArrayTwoOrMore<string>` you can have `ArrayTwoOrMore<Item>`. To change it to `ArrayOneOrMore`, just copy the `type ArrayTwoOrMore` definition and remove the `1: T` line.

Comment: Although this approach works for array declarations, when you are transforming a non-empty array into something else using `Array#map`, TypeScript will not understand that the output has a `0` key: `Property '0' is missing in type 'MyType[]' but required in type '{ 0: MyType; }'`.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. TS now interprets this type to mean that the array has one and only one element. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67026991/5091709 works.

Answer (score 39):

This is an old question and the answer is fine (it helped me as well), but I just stumbled across this solution as well while playing.

I had already defined a typed Tuple (`type Tuple<T> = [T, T];`), and then below that, I had defined array of two or more as described above (`type ArrayOfTwoOrMore<T> = { 0: T, 1: T } & T[];`).

It occurred to me to try using the `Tuple<T>` structure in place of `{ 0: T, 1: T }`, like so:

`type ArrayOfTwoOrMore<T> = [T, T, ...T[]];`

And it worked. Nice! It's a little more concise and perhaps able to be clearer in some use-cases.

Worth noting is that a tuple doesn't *have* to be two items of the same type. Something like `['hello', 2]` is a valid tuple. In my little code snippet, it just happens to be a suitable name and it needs to contain two elements of the same type.

Answer (score 21):

Expanding on Oleg's answer you can also create a type for arrays of arbitrary minimum length:

```js
type BuildArrayMinLength<
  T,
  N extends number,
  Current extends T[]
> = Current['length'] extends N
  ? [...Current, ...T[]]
  : BuildArrayMinLength<T, N, [...Current, T]>;

type ArrayMinLength<T, N extends number> = BuildArrayMinLength<T, N, []>;

const bad: ArrayMinLength<number, 2> = [1]; // Type '[number]' is not assignable to type '[number, number, ...number[]]'.
const good: ArrayMinLength<number, 2> = [1, 2];
```

Based on [Crazy, Powerful TypeScript 4.1 Features](https://instil.co/blog/crazy-powerful-typescript-41/).

Comment: This is really cool - I didn't realize TS can infer what the length would be like that. It even knows when you're casting incorrectly - typing `[1] as ArrayMinLength<string, 4>` gives a very clear and correct error.

Answer (score 7):

```js
type FixedTwoArray<T> = [T,T]
interface TwoOrMoreArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    0: T
    1: T
}

let x: FixedTwoArray<number> = [1,2];
let y: TwoOrMoreArray<string> = ['a','b','c'];
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgDwgEwCoHcD2BBATrgQxAB5UA+KAXigG1UAaVAXQCg4A7YCXAMwIGNoGTAHlcAWUy4IeQiXJQICLu2QBnKLKKkKAbxZRDUAAwAuKKgNGAjOcsBfFiwA2EYFATn4SNFi0l2AFcAWwAjbgpqGmt6ACYmAG4XNygQOywxSWl-YjVgXA4Ac0jaAHICUvpS0MrS-lLEoA)

Answer (score 4):

By building on the excellent work in the other answers here, I ended up with the following custom generic that I feel reads a little more cleanly and can provide array types of both exact and minimum lengths.

```
type BuildArrayOf<
    Quantifier extends 'exactly' | 'at least',
    Count extends number,
    Type,
    Current extends Type[]
    > = Current['length'] extends Count
    ? Quantifier extends 'exactly'
    ? [...Current]
    : [...Current, ...Type[]]
    : BuildArrayOf<Quantifier, Count, Type, [...Current, Type]>;

/** An array of a given type comprised of either exactly or at least a certain count of that type. */
type ArrayOf<Quantifier extends 'exactly' | 'at least', Count extends number, Type> = BuildArrayOf<
    Quantifier,
    Count,
    Type,
    []
>;

declare function needsExactlyTwo(strings: ArrayOf<'exactly', 2, string>): void

needsExactlyTwo(["onlyOne"]) // error
needsExactlyTwo(["one", "two"]) // valid
needsExactlyTwo(["one", "two", "three"]) // error

declare function needsAtLeastThree(strings: ArrayOf<'at least', 3, string>): void

needsAtLeastThree(["onlyOne"]) // error
needsAtLeastThree(["one", "two"]) // error
needsAtLeastThree(["one", "two", "three"]) // valid
needsAtLeastThree(["one", "two", "three", "four"]) // valid
```

You can also [check it out in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgSwDYBMCCAnDBDEB5AMwB4BYAKCkqgEU5sA7YBAhCDKCAD2AnpQGcoAci7YAxsCQghUAD7DswKEgjZ%20wIQBpyVKAGEA9nEYduvAVHpwAtgCM22ilQAq4CI9164WXkq48%20QVdIAG0AXR0qAD4oAF59bwxfEKEVegBzYAALITDTAItDY2BIygB%20GjpGZlZ2f3NBEU5xSWlSqAqQgDoerx9GCKdKAC4obt7E300oHq7giHDB3VH4ZHQsXEIiWgYmFgd9I0Zp%20enxrr6k46h5sKiAbnJyAHoAKleoNHoobA2QKAMBB%20UHSCAAbrwoKBIFAxAZrGAMAh%20BAUACgRAENk2KYWlIAexFMpVOpgWI2MBsAhvnDiuioVkidCIF0oK9nuRmZ8-lsdtV9nUzIFhKIJFIZPIhESVGoNNMiiZ6sKrHYDvMYvFVqhMDh8MR2ny9rUPFQFcATZRTu1wuQHk8yCgIGIkL9oARjBIEAZvvQIKj%20ABRZpikDOADuBgAFOokRl%20KMdZtiE08dJpgAmaYx6npKIASlGYIMCBQ9t9-qDqfDUZCACJvVI8L7a2E81Bns8OFgDBhyOWBJWQ9XI3XvRBa9Na8AIy22x2oGDsEgS32-QPg61h6Pm5PpwYJ1Ap1kkuPW%203O2wMD37Y7na6oO76J7vZY1-w0MAADIk4DOY9%206NgFjdJ425XUtilJQZXULQoAAZizICc3zQti1LMhV39D9v1lP8TxHet6EbZsz3nS9rzIft3y-H88IA7dx13GdSIvbte0ot9sNo-8IAIscDynGddx42dzwXJcVw4rCaNwni%20J3Q89wE7ITwEggjAwUT50XZd0KAA).

Answer (score 0):

This typescript definition file can limit the size of array by both minimum and maximum boundaries. Copy the whole thing into a single file and the exported type `ArrayOf` is used to accomplish the desired behavior.

```ts
type MaxArrayLength<Type, Count extends number> = BuildArrayOf<
  "exactly",
  Count,
  Type,
  []
> extends [Type, ...infer Rest]
  ? [Type, ...Rest] | MaxArrayLength<Type, Rest["length"]>
  : Count extends 1
  ? [] | [Type]
  : [];

type BuildArrayOf<
  Quantifier extends "exactly" | "min" | "max",
  Count extends number,
  Type,
  Current extends Type[]
> = Quantifier extends "max"
  ? MaxArrayLength<string, Count>
  : Current["length"] extends Count
  ? Quantifier extends "exactly"
    ? [...Current]
    : [...Current, ...Type[]]
  : BuildArrayOf<Quantifier, Count, Type, [...Current, Type]>;

type NonNegativeInteger<T extends number> = number extends T
  ? never
  : `${T}` extends `-${string}` | `${string}.${string}`
  ? never
  : T;

export type ArrayOf<
  Type,
  MinLength extends number | undefined = undefined,
  MaxLength extends number | undefined = undefined
> = MinLength extends number
  ? NonNegativeInteger<MinLength> extends never
    ? never
    : MaxLength extends number
    ? NonNegativeInteger<MaxLength> extends never
      ? never
      : MinLength extends MaxLength
      ? BuildArrayOf<"exactly", MinLength, Type, []>
      : BuildArrayOf<"exactly", MinLength, Type, []> extends [
          Type,
          ...infer Rest
        ]
      ? Exclude<
          BuildArrayOf<"max", MaxLength, Type, []>,
          BuildArrayOf<"max", Rest["length"], Type, []>
        >
      : MinLength extends 1
      ? Exclude<BuildArrayOf<"max", MaxLength, Type, []>, []>
      : BuildArrayOf<"max", MaxLength, Type, []>
    : BuildArrayOf<"min", MinLength, Type, []>
  : MaxLength extends number
  ? NonNegativeInteger<MaxLength> extends never
    ? never
    : BuildArrayOf<"max", MaxLength, Type, []>
  : Type[];
```

The usage is simple. Take a look:

```ts
const arrayWithNoBoundary: ArrayOf<string> = []; // equals to string[]

const arrayWithMinimumLength: ArrayOf<string, 2> = ["", ""] // equals to [string, string, ...string[]]

const arrayWithMaximumLength: ArrayOf<string, undefined, 2> = []; // equals to ([] | [string] | [string, string])

const arrayWithBothLimits: ArrayOf<string, 3, 5> = ["", "", "", ""] // equals to ([string, string, string] | [string, string, string, string] | [string, string, string, string, string])

const arrayOfFixedSie: ArrayOf<string, 3, 3> = ["", "", ""] // equals to [string, string, string]
```

Invalid usages will turn the type into `never`. Here is a list of all invalid usages:

```
type Invalid = ArrayOf<SomeType, number, number> // Min and max must be of type either undefined or an exact positive integer. The 'number' type is not accepted

type Invalid = ArrayOf<SomeType, -1, 1.2> // Negative numbers or numbers with decimals are invalid for both min and max length.

type Invalid = ArrayOf<SomeType, 2, 1> // Min length can not be grater than max length
```