# In React, how to restrict the number of children with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a "Columns" component. It should only take either one or two children.

How do I restrict the number of children using Typescript?

Comment: Props `ColumnLeft: Column; ColumnRight?: Columm` and don't use children, or validate children on runtime and throw error.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work

```js
import * as React from "react";

type ChildType = React.ReactElement;

interface ColumnProps {
  children: [ChildType, ChildType] | ChildType; // Either 2 of this type or one
}

const Column: React.FC<ColumnProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Column>
        <div>Test 1</div>
        <div>Test 2</div>
      </Column>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49910890/3008693) I think this might work?

```
type Column = {
    foo: string;
}

type ArrayOneOrMore<T> = {
    0: T
} & Array<T>

type Columns = ArrayOneOrMore<Column>;

const ColumnOne = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

const ColumnTwo = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

const WithOneColumn: Columns = [ColumnOne, ColumnTwo];
const WithTwoColumns: Columns = [ColumnOne];
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=45#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwK4FsB2UC8UDeBYAKCmKgDM44AuKAZ2ACcBLNAcwG5CBfQw0SKAIL16AQxAB5NBHH0AsnHoQAPABUAfFlyESUAAzUVXKADJBwsarU8CfaPGToamoaIlSZ8xUvuo0ajgSEAMZwaHSwiL6S0Nj4RCTkVFAA5ABGIvTJXNYhYcARDmgqAO5wmnE6idRpGVkE3IEEueEA6ozAABbRPujUPWGaANr90QA0Bb4lcAC6Ac35bZ1T-TR9kY5DI1KzQA)