# Interface for function with multiple arguments?

Tags: typescript

I have a function where the first argument must be a string. There can be an unlimited number of arguments after that or none at all:

```
const myFunction = (arg1: string, ...rest: any) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Can I make a type or interface that specifies both `arg1` and `...rest`? I'm asking as other functions have the same arguments and I'd like to reuse the typings.

Comment: `type FunctionType = (arg1: string, ...rest: any[]) => void`? Or just the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by taking an answer from [TypeScript array with minimum length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49910889/3001761), and using it as the type for a rest argument, for example:

```
type OneOrMore<T> = { 0: T } & Array<T>;

// or allow the rest to be a wider type, like any:
// type OneOrMore<T, S extends T = T> = { 0: T } & Array<S>;
```

You can either define a [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types) using this:

```
type MyFunction = (...args: OneOrMore<string>) => void;

const myFunction: MyFunction = (...args) => { /* use args */ };
```

or use it directly:

```
function anotherFunction(...args: OneOrMore<string>) { /* use args */ }
```

Now calling with one or more arguments is permitted, but calling with no arguments gives e.g.

```
Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OneOrMore<string>'.
  Property '0' is missing in type '[]' but required in type '{ 0: string; }'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhGAnAsgeyRAPAFQHxQC8UA3lAAwBcUOUAvlAGRQCCSSAhiLngNwBQ-UJCgoQAMQCucAMbAAlmjhEoACgB0mjkgDmAZ2rxEqDNj3Ak8uDrwBKIgQBuaeQBMB-GUvNQAthOk5RThqMSlZBSUVDS1dPXtCAjIAegAqKEk9aG19KFTk+g9-cKClVVsBYsDIuFUAIgAzNDQ6iv4qiOD6ppaAGig6gCNtVoEgA)

---

However, note that your implementation can't name that first parameter independently; the following:

```
const myFunction: MyFunction = (arg, ...args) => { /* use arg and args */ };
```

results in:

```
Type '(arg: string, ...args: string[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'MyFunction'.
  Types of parameters 'arg' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'OneOrMore<string>' is not assignable to type '[arg: string, ...args: string[]]'.
```