# Array will never be empty but typescript does not know

Tags: typescript

I am getting this error `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more` from:

```
    if (initialValues.length > 0) {
      return Object.assign(...initialValues);
    }
```

I guess it is complaining that `initialValues` could be empty. However, the if condition guarantees that it won't be empty. What do I do to make typescript realize this?

Comment: Eh, this isn't exactly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006111/is-it-possible-to-define-a-non-empty-array-type-in-typescript) but it's strongly related.  I had marked it as a duplicate but I'll undo that.

Comment: FYI, I've updated the answer below to show how to do this with types if you prefer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allowing a [`length` check as a type guard](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38000) was deemed "too complex" to be added to TypeScript (thanks [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for the link!).

You can take a least three approaches:

#### Destructure and provide the target explicitly

Since it's not getting it from the `length` check, I'd probably give it the target object explicitly, like this:

```typescript
const [target, ...sources] = initialValues;
if (target) {
    return Object.assign(target, ...sources);
}
```

It's happy with that.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4EsB2blqhAangK4gDOAXPAPYBGAVuMgNoC6A3AFAdhUampNksAOYoANPAB000lSIwwZFvAC86LDjyEIJUpzQAzeAAohMUcgCU8AN4d4D+Dz6padVfADy9RpKilSNGEMUxFxKRk5BTJLTkd4AHoEiMkOAF8gA)

#### Define it as a non-empty array

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56006703/2887218p) shows how to define a type for a non-empty array:

```typescript
type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];
```

If `initialValues` is known at compile-time to always have at least one element, define it using that type:

```typescript
let initialValues: NonEmptyArray<YourObjectType>;
```

Then you can remove the `if`, since you know it'll always be true:

```typescript
return Object.assign(...initialValues);
```

#### Use a type guard

But if it could be empty and the runtime check is needed, you can define a type guard function:

```typescript
function isNotEmpty<T>(arr: T[]): arr is NonEmptyArray<T> {
    return arr.length > 0;
}
```

Then it's:

```typescript
if (isNotEmpty(initialValues)) {
    return Object.assign(...initialValues);
}
```

---

Huge thanks to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) and [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) for helping with this answer.

Comment: A curious observation - [I tried a different approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4EsB2blqhAangK4gDOAXPAPYBGAVuMgNoC6A3AFAdoBm8AFFGQAZEFFLIAjP0zZcBYmQCUS+AG8O8LfDBUME6vXgBeeAHl6jAHTjSaAOYZ+Vl7Jx5CEEqSWdt8AHoA+BcrDgBfLh4iDDAcPXghUXEpAB4AFQA+QRgYSnTWJUpYGHRSdQAGfPD4ADJ4ApZ1TW04ZCIYDETcqyQMe2QAC3hM+ArOSKA) using a type guard + [minimum length array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49910889) but the compiler throws the same error.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, I tried to come at it like that too (though in a different way, `[object] & object[]`, which doesn't work correctly anyway). Not sure why.

Comment: @VLAZ Just adding in a property whose key is `0` doesn't imply anything about the `length` property in TypeScript (it would be surprising if that happened for any *normal* object type, so it's not surprising it doesn't magically happen when one side of the intersection is an array). You could use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56006703/2887218p) for something that the compiler actually can understand

Comment: @jcalz [perfect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4EsB2blqhAangK4gDOAXPANoD2ARgFbjIA089TYyAugNwBQ-NADN4ACijIAMiCilkARjGZsuAsTIBKTfADe-eIfhgaGee0bwAvPADyjZgDo5pNAHMMYx95U48hCBJSTQEjeAB6cPhvR34AX0FhIgwuNFN4SRk5RQAeABUAPgkYGEo8qm5NSlgYdFJ4ADlTAFEAWwAHZABPAEESqC78gr0DIzhkIhgMDJLHJAw3ZAALeGGABgEE-m72hCaMNs7e-sHC62o8thjy7j4gA)! I had just started reading about variadic tuple types as they seemed relevant. I just knew of their existence but not more.

Comment: @jcalz - That's **fantastic**, I was off on a quest for a minimum-length-array. Are you going to post an answer, or should I add the type-based solution to the above?

Comment: If you want to modify your answer to include that info it's fine with me. I won't add an answer myself.

Comment: @VLAZ - I've added that approach and CW'd the answer.

Comment: In case it matters, [microsoft/TypeScript#38000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38000) is the declined request to make `array.length > 0` work as a type guard.