# Type definition for array with minimun and maximum length in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How can I create a type definition for array with minimun and maximum length, as in:

```
var my_arr:my_type<type, {start: 1, end: 3}>;

my_arr = [1] - pass
my_arr = [1,2] - pass
my_arr = [1,2,3] - pass
my_arr = [1,2,3,4] - fail
my_arr = [1, "string"] - fail
```

I.E. provide the type of the elements in the array and a start index and end index of length such that if the length is less than the start index it fails, or if the length is bigger than the end index it fails.

I've found this solution for a fixed length array online:

```
type SingleLengthArray<
  T,
  N extends number,
  R extends readonly T[] = []
> = R["length"] extends N ? R : SingleLengthArray<T, N, readonly [T, ...R]>;
```

And I was able to create a type that works if the length of the array is either equal to the start index or end index but nothing inbetween:

```
type MultipleLengthArray<
  T,
  N extends { start: number; end: number },
  R extends readonly T[] = []
> = SingleLengthArray<T, N["start"], R> | SingleLengthArray<T, N["end"], R>;
```

What I think would work if it's possible is to create an array of numbers from the start index up to the end index(i.e. start index = 1, end index = 5 => array would be [1,2,3,4,5]) and iterate over the array and like

```
type MultipleLengthArray<T, N extends {start: number, end:number}, R extends readonly T[] = []> = for each value n in array => SingleLengthArray<T, n1, R> | SingleLengthArray<T, n2, R> | ... | SingleLengthArray<T, n_last, R>
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript array with minimum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910889/typescript-array-with-minimum-length)

Comment: Minimum I get, but why would you *ever* need to specify the *maximum* length of an array via types? Unless we're talking about using an array as a tuple, in which case it has an exact length, or one of several kinds of tuples, in which case it's a union of fixed-length tuple types, I don't get why you'd need to strongly type the maximum length. Not to mention that arrays are mutable and growable so the typechecker could **definitely** lull you into a false sense of security with that.

Comment: @JaredSmith I need an array that has as parameters this enum {V, A, S} and it can have either a length of 3, 4 or 5, and all the possible orders of those enums(i.e. [S,S,S] or [V,A,S] or [S,A,V] or [S,S,S,V,A] etc.. If you know of a better method please let me know. And for the growable problem, I only need to replace the original array with another one, i.e. [V,A,S] replaced by [S,S,S,V,A], I'm never going to use methods such as push or other ones that modify the array's length directly(because I don't need to)

Comment: 3, 4, or 5, is just `[T,T,T] | [T,T,T,T] | [T,T,T,T,T]`  T been your enum.

Comment: In addition to what Keith said, I understand the criteria, but who cares if there are *extra* elements (of the correct type) in the array? Slice the part you care about and call it a day. Way less error-prone than trying to make the type system bend over backwards.

Comment: @Keith I know but that was only an example, I will have bigger size arrays and I'd rather not type out arrays from length 1 up to 80 or something similar.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvKpYw) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes this was what I was looking for, thank you. You can post the answer so I can accept it. Could you please explain a bit how it works as I've tried to understand it but I failed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret this as looking for a type function we can call `TupMinMax<T, Min, Max>` which resolves to a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) where each element is of type `T`, and whose length must be between `Min` and `Max` inclusive.  We can represent this as a single tuple type with [optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) at every index greater than `Min` and less than or equal to `Max`.  (Unless you turn on [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), this will allow `undefined` values for these optional properties also, but I'm going to assume that's not a big deal).  So you want, for example, `TupMinMax<number, 1, 3>` to be `[number, number?, number?]`.

Here's one approach:

```
type TupMinMax<
  T, Min extends number, Max extends number,
  A extends (T | undefined)[] = [], O extends boolean = false
  > = O extends false ? (
    Min extends A['length'] ? TupMinMax<T, Min, Max, A, true> : 
    TupMinMax<T, Min, Max, [...A, T], false>
  ) : Max extends A['length'] ? A : 
    TupMinMax<T, Min, Max, [...A, T?], false>;
```

This is a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types), where `TupMinMax<T, Min, Max>` has some extra parameters `A` and `O` to act as *accumulators* to store intermediate state.  Specifically, `A` will store the tuple result so far, while `O` will be either `true` or `false` representing whether we have entered into the optional part of the tuple.  It starts out `false` and becomes `true` later.

The first conditional check is `O extends false ? (...) : (...)`.  If `O` is `false` then we haven't yet reached the minimum length and the elements should be required.  Then we check `Min extends A['length']` to see if the accumulator has reached the minimum length yet.  If so, then we immediately switch `O` to `true` with the same `A` accumulator.  If not, then we append a required `T` element to the end of `A`.  If `O` is not `false` then it's `true` and we  then check `Max extends A['length']` to see if the accumulator has reached the maximum length yet.  If so then we are done and evaluate to `A`.  If not, then we append an optional `T` element to the end of `A`.

Let's test it out:

```
type OneTwoOrThreeNumbers = TupMinMax<number, 1, 3>;
// type OneTwoOrThreeNumbers = [number, number?, number?]

let nums: OneTwoOrThreeNumbers;
nums = []; // error
nums = [1]; // okay
nums = [1, 2]; // okay
nums = [1, 2, 3]; // okay
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // error
nums = [1, "two", 3]; // error

type BetweenTenAndThirtyStrings = TupMinMax<string, 10, 30>;
/* type BetweenTenAndThirtyStrings = [string, string, string, string, 
     string, string, string, string, string, string, string?, string?, 
     string?,  string?, ... 15 more ...?, string?] */
let strs: BetweenTenAndThirtyStrings;
strs = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"]
```

Looks good.  The tail recursion means that the compiler should be able to handle a recursion depth of ~1,000 levels, so if your tuple length range is even as large as several hundred it should compile okay.

Note that such recursive types can be fragile and prone to nasty edge cases.  If you like to torture yourself and your compiler you try passing something other than non-negative whole numbers as `Min` and `Max`, or pass in a `Min` which is greater than `Max`.  The recursion base case will never be reached and the compiler will, if you're lucky, complain about recursion depth; and if you're not lucky, it will consume lots of CPU and make your computer hot:

```
//  followed by 
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
// type Oops = TupMinMax<any, 10, 1>; 
// type Oops2 = TupMinMax<any, 3.5 4>;
```

So be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmAsgSwHaIIYA8A8AoKWAGihVSgi2AlQBMBnKVOAWwCMIAnEzLCqmgyasO3AlACC-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-LUGH+ZI49HU4yk7Ls7H87nI4XM6IcUIa8XK+X+ep273u8y+4Px5IxygMIArFAWFLoMd9zPzlB68i8Izt6y4wnXkmO12PY5vO-J4MOQoBjCoZQAGurQQG8LwW68FXvBABs8EAOzwQAHPBACc8EwhWRFQSQkFweRMKIVRyGGHcYqALwbgCku4xgDdOyxlzOE49h-rQUBsCAsDNlAaClm4wDIBgkn2OQyCMJQADGED0PQyAAG4QE4Qm0H8YBQG4-FgPYqnIGw2miagWioMg1B9HWaIxpY9hgIWbTFrgbggJWsJIlADlNo8zmubqgRFlsnmoN5Lp9Debq1ngQA)

Comment: Great answer with great explanation, thank you so much. Just one thing, maybe I understood incorrectly but on the line "If so, then we immediately switch O to false", should this not be true instead corresponding to this line Min extends A['length'] ? TupMinMax<T, Min, Max, A, true> ?

Comment: Yeah, whoops, typo.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to leverage a Tuple with Optional Properties.  Tuples have a specified length (allowing for the optionality of its properties).

```
enum E { V, A, S }

type TupleOfE = [ E, E, E, E?, E? ]

const e: TupleOfE = [ E.V, E.A, E.S, E.S, E.S ]

console.log(e)
console.log(e.filter(e => e === E.S))
```

Comment: This solves my problem, partially. The example I gave in the comments was not the only case scenario, I will have bigger sized arrays with the similar logic, so is there a cleaner way to create TupleOfE? I'd rather not type out 80 E's hahaha.