# Array declaration in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I started learning TS and I have a doubt around Array in TS.

Code -

```js
let array: Array<number> = [123];
array = [5,6];
array= [];
```

In the above code TS compiler is not throwing any error. But I have a doubt, when I am declaring the `array` to be `Array<number>` in this scenario when I am setting my array to a blank array it should throw error but its not.

Is there a way in TS where I can define array in a manner that it should always have at least a number in an Array and in case of blank or no values in an Array it should throws a compile time error ?

Comment: why would it throw an error? type does not mean it has to have a value

Comment: An empty array is an array of numbers with zero numbers in it.

Comment: In all languages I can think of assigning an empty array is legal syntax. Why should it not be in this case?

Comment: More precisely, it DOES have a value. The value is an empty array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript array with minimum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910889/typescript-array-with-minimum-length)

Comment: @David : Thanks a lot, most upvoted answer in the linked question is what I am looking for.